# Flink-connector-kafka giving Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am working on project for with flink-kafka-connector and using below dependency in my pom

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
   <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1-1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

whenever I am submitting my job I getting ***Could not initialize class org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig***

stacktrace as below

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Global failure triggered by OperatorCoordinator for 'Source: Kafka - Source -> Flat Map -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer' (operator 61252f73469d3ffba207c548d29a0267).
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.failJob(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:624)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator$QuiesceableContext.failJob(RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.failJob(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:395)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinator.lambda$runInEventLoop$10(SourceCoordinator.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(AdminClient.java:39)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.getKafkaAdminClient(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:410)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.start(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinator.lambda$start$1(SourceCoordinator.java:233)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinator.lambda$runInEventLoop$10(SourceCoordinator.java:469)
    ... 8 more
```

I have check there isn't any conflicting dependency. All the required dependencies are packed in my jar.
Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

For `ClassNotFoundException` errors, this is almost assuredly an issue where your given Flink application didn't compile one or more of the expected dependencies when you packaged it (e.g. compiled into a jar/shaded jar) prior to deploying the job. Since they aren't packaged in the application, you'll encounter these errors at runtime when the classes are referenced by your code.

As you mentioned, you referenced the appropriate Kafka Connector dependency (`flink-connector-kafka`) however you may want to ensure that Kafka client library itself is added as a dependency (`kafka-clients`)  and available and both are using the `compile` scope:

```
<!-- Connector Dependency -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
   <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
   <version>${kafka.version}</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Client Dependency -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
   <version>${kafka.version}</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I know that `compile` scope is the default and shouldn't be necessary, but I've seen cases when building Flink-based jars that seemed to *want* it there, so I'd recommend trying it first with it explicitly defined before removing it.

Comment: still same issue.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your jar that gets packaged up to confirm that dependency is present? Those should be the only two dependencies that you need, but if they aren't present at runtime, it's likely they weren't packaged in the jar.

Comment: I'm suspecting you're including a different Kafka Clients version then the one that's used in `3.0.1-1.18` - It should match with https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-kafka/blob/v3.0.1/pom.xml#L53

Comment: Yeah, as @MartijnVisser mentions, note in my example above the versions of both of those should match. You didn't mention the specific version of the client that you were trying but I'd suspect this could be the issue as well.